# Google analytics enhanced ecommerce step different page

Tags: javascript, c#, google-analytics

I'm using google analytics enhanced ecommerce now I have a problem is the last step fires when user submit the checkout form to a payment page(not my own),and when user completed the payment , the payment page will return info to my server.My problem is when I receive the return infos and use C# WebClient to send ga values,
and the GA Sales Performance page shows the list of paid orders,but there's no product info in the order detail.I've tried send all checkout step data by javascript it works.
So if the GA doesn't allow mix both javascript and server side ? Thanks

Code is below:

```
//Function to get ga event value;
var getGaValue = function (eventAction, eventLabel) {
    var obj = {
        "eventCategory": "GA Payment Event Test",
        "eventAction": eventAction,
    };

    if (eventLabel)
        obj["eventLabel"] = eventLabel;
    return obj;
};

//PageView.
var pageViewFunc = function(items) {
    items.forEach(function (item, index) {
        ga(tracker + ".ec:addImpression", {
            "id": item.Id,
            "name": item.ItemName,
            "brand": item.Brand,
            "price": item.Price,
            "list": "Items List",
            "position": index
        });
    });

    ga(tracker + ".send", "pageview");
};

//Checkout step 1.
var checkoutFunc = function(items) {
    items.forEach(function (item, index) {
        ga(tracker + ".ec:addProduct", {
            "id": item.Id,
            "name": item.ItemName,
            "brand": item.Brand,
            "price": item.Price,
            "quantity": item.Qty
        });
    });

    ga(tracker + ".ec:setAction", "checkout", {
        "step": 1,
        "option": "Checkout"
    });

    ga(tracker + ".send", "event", getGaValue("Checkout"));

};

//Checkout step 2
var payFunc = function (items) {        
    items.forEach(function (item, index) {
        ga(tracker + ".ec:addProduct", {
            "id": item.Id,
            "name": item.ItemName,
            "brand": item.Brand,
            "price": item.Price,
            "quantity": item.Qty
        });
    });

    ga(tracker + ".ec:setAction", "checkout", {
        "step": 2,
        "option": "Pay"
    });

    ga(tracker + ".send", "event", getGaValue("Pay"));
    //Submit form to payment page.       
    form.submit();
};
```

And when payment page returns info:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect";
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    Order order=OrderService.GetById("Test12345");
    IEnumerable<OrderItem> items = OrderItemService.GetByOrderId(order.Id);
    IDictionary<string, string> purchaseParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var item in items.Select((it, i) => new { it, or }))
    {
         purchaseParams.Add("pr" + item.i + "id", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.it.Id));
         purchaseParams.Add("pr" + item.i + "nm", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.it.ItemName));
         purchaseParams.Add("pr" + item.i + "br", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.it.Brand));
         purchaseParams.Add("pr" + item.i + "pr", item.it.Price);
         purchaseParams.Add("pr" + item.i + "qt", item.it.Qty);
    }
    purchaseParams.Add("pa", "purchase");
    purchaseParams.Add("ti", order.Id);
    purchaseParams.Add("tr", order.Amount);
    purchaseParams.Add("tt", "0");
    purchaseParams.Add("ts", order.ShippingFee);

    purchaseParams.Add("v", "1");
    purchaseParams.Add("tid","UA-XXXXXX");
    purchaseParams.Add("cid",order.GaClientid );
    purchaseParams.Add("t", "event");
    purchaseParams.Add("ec", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("GA Payment Event Test"));
    purchaseParams.Add("ea", "Purchase");
    purchaseParams.Add("dp", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("/Pay"));
    wc.UploadString(url, purchaseParams.ToQueryString());
}
```

Comment: I think we need some code to see what it is you are doing.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  GA shouldn't care if you send the data via JS or directly though the measurement protocol.   My guess is there is something off with your code.

Comment: Mixing JS and serverside calls are possible in principle, but it seems really hard to connect those calls into a session. Even if you use the same client id GA might start a new session (since source attribution changes between client and server calls). In any case I agree that you probably have to show some code.

Comment: Thanks for replying!I post my code here,And you can see I've saved the GA client ID in database.